# Install git in FreeBSD

Tags: git, freebsd

I have freeBSD 8.4, and I want to install **git**. I tried the following steps:

```
$ pkg_add -r git
Error: Unable to get http://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/ports/amd64/packages-8.4-release/Latest/git.tbz: Not Found
pkg_add: unable to fetch 'http://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/ports/amd64/packages-8.4-release/Latest/git.tbz' by URL
```

Then I tried:

```
$ cd /usr/ports/devel/git
$ make install clean
.
.
twofish-amd64.S: Assembler messages:
twofish-amd64.S:195: Error: `(%r8d,%r9d,2)' is not a valid 64 bit base/index expression
twofish-amd64.S:195: Error: `(%r8d,%r9d,2)' is not a valid 64 bit base/index expression
twofish-amd64.S:196: Error: `(%r8d,%r9d,2)' is not a valid 64 bit base/index expression
twofish-amd64.S:196: Error: `(%r8d,%r9d,2)' is not a valid 64 bit base/index expression
so on....

*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/security/libgcrypt/work/libgcrypt-1.7.3/cipher.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/security/libgcrypt/work/libgcrypt-1.7.3.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/security/libgcrypt/work/libgcrypt-1.7.3.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/security/libgcrypt.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/security/libgcrypt.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/textproc/libxslt.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/textproc/libxslt.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/textproc/xmlto.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/textproc/xmlto.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/devel/git.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/devel/git.
```

I saw in various forums but failed. I have seen in some freebsd that git application is installed and present in /usr/local/bin/git.
I tried `pkg install git` too. but that too failed.

If there is any way, please tell me.

Comment: I think you are better of on SuperUser or Server Fault, those are other sub-sites of StackExchange.

Comment: You probably have an old/out of date ports tree, or you have an updated version that isn't compatible with your OS version/toolchain.  Considering you are running an OLD, and End Of Life'd version of FreeBSD, you should probably look at upgrading to something supported (10.3 at this time), before you go much further

Comment: I have upgraded my ports tree using portsnap and I need to use freebsd 8.4 only.

Comment: I would concentrate on resolving the `pkg_add` error.  http://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/ports/distfiles/README.txt seems to contain a hint.

Comment: @triplee, can u tell me how to proceed with these ports-distfiles?

Comment: I manually searched the link of git.tbz and set the PACKAGESITE variable and performed the pkg_add command. I used the freebsd 8.1 ports tree link having git.tbz. 
[FreeBSD 8.1 ports](http://ftp-archive.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD-Archive/ports/amd64/packages-8.1-release/Latest/)

And using this:
[Error: Unable to get ftp](http://sharadchhetri.com/2013/07/21/error-unable-to-get-ftpftp-freebsd-orgpubfreebsdportsi386packages-9-0-releaselatest/)

@triplee, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Search for the ports tree having **git.tbz**. One is here
[FreeBSD 8.1 ports tree](http://ftp-archive.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD-Archive/ports/amd64/packages-8.1-release/Latest/)

Now set the environment variable PACKAGESITE and do these as shown below:

```
$ setenv PACKAGESITE http://ftp-archive.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD-Archive/ports/amd64/packages-8.1-release/Latest/
$ pkg_add -r git
```

That will work good.

Comment: Just for the record, `setenv` is correct for `csh` and derivatives; if yours is a Bourne shell (Bash etc) you would instead use `PACKAGESITE='http://whatever.blah/blah'; export PACKAGESITE`